# What is the meaning of "Hay que volver a sentir"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

I am attempting to translate a travel advertisement for Dénia, Spain, and I am getting stuck on the catchphrase "Hay que volver a sentir".

To me this translates as "A necessary return to sensation" or "You must return to feeling". Nothing I can think of captures the essence of what I think the advertisement is trying to get across. The ad has a photo of a woman relaxing and reading on a white sand beach.

What is the meaning of "Hay que volver a sentir"?

Comment: Welcome to the site. There is a nuance about the translations we do here. Since we are a site about Spanish **we translate into Spanish** (with some restrictions, see the [help]) and we explain the meaning of something which is in a different language or look for an equivalent in Spanish. **We don't really translate into English**, but we can clarify or discuss the meaning of a Spanish expression using English. Bottom line, the best answer should not be the best English translation, but the best clarification about the meaning of that Spanish expression (using the language of your choice).

Comment: Personally I would just translate as "Feel again". Sure, there might be some info lost in translation, but this translation prioritizes sense to "completeness" to get a more accurate, simpler and _catchier_ slogan. Also, please take into account the comment above and see if you can rephrase (edit) the question to ask about the meaning or intention of the sentence rather than requesting a translation into English. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should go to ELU.

Comment: Get your groove back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said in the comments, we don't translate into English, but as it seems you have a doubt with the meaning of "volver", let's focus into that.

You're using "return" as a translation. That is a valid translation in other context. We can find that meaning in the DLE:

> [**volver**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c33Avl1)
>
> 20. *intr*. Ir al lugar de donde se partió.

But in this case I think the idea with "volver" is to do something (in this case to feel) one more time. So in this case we can use this other meaning of volver:

> 23. *intr.* Repetir o reiterar lo que antes se ha hecho. Volver A entrar, A empezar.

In this case, to repeat, or do again, something that was done before. Look at these examples:

> Quiero volver a jugar -> I want to play again
>
> No vuelvas a hacerlo -> Don't do it again

So a possible translation could be:

> It's necessary to feel again

or

> We/you need to feel (it?) again

Comment: Alternative: We/you need to feel (it?) again.

Comment: @DGaleano incluí tu propuesta con la actualización de la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is about living the sensation again. It’s about feelings or experiences; not only repeating the activity but being in that moment again. More like going back in time and going through the same experience. It’s a tough translation but I’ll give some examples and I’m sure you can capture the idea and provide a better English phrase:

> Let’s live again
>   Let’s feel again